# Replacing sub floor, that is under a concrete floor

Tags: concrete, floor, subfloor

House was built in the mid 60s. It's on piers with a craw space. While having it leveled, we discovered rot under the half bath. The water leak is fixed. However discovered the sub floor that needs replaced has a 1 1/2 inch concrete floor on top of it, covered with tile. No visual damage or even floor shake from the top side.

Question since the floor beam will need to have rot removed and the sub floor needs replaced. Can the new sub floor be installed from under the house, rather than busting out the concrete and tile floor?

Comment: Would you want to work under 1000 pounds of concrete as you remove the supports for it?  It can be done, pictures of what there is would help, but will probably add 4 times the cost and labour.

Comment: I think it is unlikely a concrete floor, 1 1/2" sounds like the mortar/grout bed for tile. There is no way to save it, pal.

Comment: I have photos, but can't figure out how to upload here. It could be mortar, to be honest, I wouldn't know the difference. Can tell you it's hard and tough! Took out the bottom half of the bathroom wall (that was tiled) and found the same, but not as thick, just under an inch thick. The bathrooms (that share a wall) are the only places in the house that have this. The rest is hardwood on plank sub floor.

Comment: A concrete floor should be something like 5-6 inches thick, I think, 4 inches at a minimum.  Sounds like tile grout, might be thicker than normal grout in order to make it level and/or flush with something else.